# What would cause a USB bus under current and how could it be corrected?

Tags: usb, motherboard, power

I have a new motherboard that is exhibiting a strange issue with the USB (2.0 only) bus. I am having some of my devices losing power and led lights start flicker when I am playing games and other things that would load on the system.

The type of board I have is the ASUS RoG Rampage IV Extreme. When I lookup information about the problem I saw that other people had a similar issue.

Obviously moving to my other ports solves the problem but now I have USB 3 ports being taken up by devices that are not USB 3 which is a waste for me.

Is there anything I can do to "boost" the voltage to the bus?

Comment: Under-*volted* or under-*amped*? The voltage should be constant for USB - 5V.

Comment: Yeah my bad I meant under amped, I am not getting enough current.

Comment: Sure thing. At what current drain do you start experiencing problems?

Comment: uhh I have no idea, how would I know what the drain is on the bus? Just add up the demand of the devices plugged in?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: The load specs often deviate from reality. Suggest putting an ammeter in series to see what the load really is.

Comment: One possibility though for the PSU, (not very well known) , some poor quality PSUs fluxuate one voltage when there is a very high load on the other, this has included both up and down.  Crasy stuff like a high load on the 12V causing the 5V to raise in voltage, and the reverse.  Important PSU quality things only discussed in the deep teardown and analise locations.

Comment: ^ for that determine that, even if there is only few items and small load on the USB , that it still occurs the same.    Is there any charging only items you could have moved to a wall plug instead of the computer? Do you have those external storage items that ride off the usb power only? Split a few things off to a power hub?

Comment: I hope you get an exciting answer, but in the meantime an answer could be a mains powered hub, or changing PSU.

Comment: @K7AAY : true, but not everyone has a multimeter and knows how to measure the current drain correctly.

Comment: @Psycogeek I can assure you it is not my power supply. I have Corsair AX760 80 plus platinum. It is brand new.

Comment: @Psycogeek Nope everything hooked the USB bus is no charging devices.

Comment: I have connected to the USB the following; Corsair K70 Keyboard, Razr Death adder 3.5G, Wireless XBOX 360 controller receiver (controller runs on AA batteries), APC UPS data cable for my battery, Nvidia 3D IR immitter, and a Logitech HD webcam.

Comment: What if there is only 1 Item,something with an led light? If others have the same issue, then you probably have to workaround it,with powered hub. which raises the question ,will connected devices have other problems, anyway (Dropping)? Volt meter.  You could wire in some changes :-) But even I wouldn't when there are small cheap powered hub that work

Comment: I could try using a powered hub. That might work.